# Detecting Javascript load event in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, internet-explorer-9, onload

I want to execute some part of my `addon` code on page load, so I'm looking for page load event in browsers.

```
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", func, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", func);

function func() {
    alert("page loaded");
    //my code here
}
```

In Firefox I'm able to catch load event, but in IE9 I'm unable to get this. Alternately, using jQuery call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //my code here
});
```

we can get this, but I need this functionality without using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

This will execute in IE9:

```
window.onload = func;
```

To modify your code:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", func, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", func);
} else {
    window['onload'] = func;
}
```

The more general event handler attachment would be:

```
function Subscribe(event, element, func) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, func, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + event, func);
    } else {
        element['on' + event] = func;
    }
}

Subscribe('load', window, func);
```

Comment: The `$(document).ready()` event is `DOMContentLoaded`, not `load`.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I am aware of that, but in the example code in the question there is window.load and $(document).ready mixed. I have answered for window.load, as well as with general subscribe function.

Comment: Problem is not with conditions. it is entering into first if condition itself, but failing at this statement "window.addEventListener("load", func, false);". same problem with second and third conditions. Thanks,

Comment: @mmh What do you mean by "failing at this statement"

Comment: I mean, after execution of "window.addEventListener("load", func, false);" , it should call "func" function.but it is not calling.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this

```
window.onload = function () {
   // do something here
};
```